# Tell postfix to merge three Authentication-Results:-Lines into one?

Tags: email, postfix

I am running a postfix mta with debian wheezy. I am using postfix-policyd-spf-python, openkdim and opendmarc. When receiving e-mails from google (google apps with own domain) for example, the header looks like this:

```
[...]
Authentication-Results: mail.xx.de; dkim=pass
    reason="1024-bit key; insecure key"
    header.d=yyy.com header.i=@yyy.com
    header.b=OswLe0N+; dkim-adsp=pass; dkim-atps=neutral<br>
[...]
Authentication-Results: mail.xx.de; spf=pass (sender SPF authorized) smtp.mailfrom=yyy.com (client-ip=2a00:1450:400c:c00::242; helo=mail-wg0-x242.google.com; envelope-from=mail@yyy.com; receiver=mail@xxx.com)
[...]
Authentication-Results: mail.xx.de; dmarc=pass header.from=yyy.com<br>
[...]
```

This means any of these programs creates it's own Authentication-Results:-Line.
Is it possible to tell postfix to merge this into one single Authentication-Results:-Line?

When I send an e-mail to google, it says:

```
[...]
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of mail@xxx.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mail@xxx.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@xxx.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=xxx.com
[...]
```

And this is exactly what I want. Just one Authentication-Results-Header.
How can I do this?

Thanks.

Regards,

Peter

Comment: You'd probably be best doing this via a milter, or an external script..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use postfix `header_checks` feature to handle your case, then the `header_checks` can't do that. Header checks only **process header line by line** until body parts.

As @NickW said, you should use milter / or external script with content filter. Of course that special milter must be placed in the bottom. With external script, you can add it via `content_filter` parameter.